# handled (past tense used for future events)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense, past-simple

Why is this sentence correct: If not ***handled*** well, it may result in a fire.

Why use past tense? How to know when to use it?

Answer (score 1):

It is a conditional sentence in the passive voice

> **If (it is) not handled well**, it may result in a fire.

The active form would be

> **If we don't handle it well**, a fire might break out.